# File upload not working on localhost express server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, ng-file-upload

I'm trying to implement [ng file upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) in a node app I'm running on localhost. I'm going off the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/0mz6ff9o/135/) but when i change the directory to download to

```
file.upload = Upload.upload({
                url: 'uploadImages',
                data: {file: file}
            });
```

I'm getting a 404:

> angular.js:10765 POST http://localhost:8888/uploadImages/ 404 (Not Found)

Do I need to set up an express route for that directory? I've attempted that, but it isn't working either with

```
app.post('/uploadImages', cors(corsOptions), function(req, res){
    res.sendfile('./uploadImages')
});
```

Not really sure where to go from here.

Comment: How you are dealing with multipart data ? I believe you need to add `express.bodyParser()` middleware and then set your directory where you need to save images

Comment: @swapnesh I am using `bodyParser`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to set up a web server like your Node Express server to accept the POST request. The way I have done this in the past was to use [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer), an Express middleware for handling multi-part uploads.

**EXAMPLE**

```
var express = require('express')
var multer = require('multer')

var app = express();

var upload = multer({
    dest: 'uploadImages/'
});

app.post('/uploadImages', upload.any(), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.files is the file uploaded, which multer will write to
  // the dest folder for you. req.body will contain the text fields,
  // if there were any.

  res.json(req.files.file);
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I was answering from my mobile phone. Had to look through some old code for an example of how I've used this in the past.

Comment: that is actually giving me the error `500: Error: Unexpected field at makeError (...node_modules/multer/lib/make-error.js:12:13)   at wrappedFileFilter (...node_modules/multer/index.js:39:19)   at Busboy.&lt;anonymous&gt; ` Any idea what that could be?

Comment: Try using just multer, not multer.single(). See my updated answer.

Comment: using the updated code, the following error is produced: `Error: Route.post() requires callback functions but got a [object Object]`

Comment: You could try upload.any(), sorry I don't have an environment to test on at the moment. Mostly writing these answers on my mobile. I would definitely recommend reading through the docs for multer, as there are a few different ways you can configure it.

Comment: That actually stopped all of the errors and it looks like it gets the file data successfully. Thank you. The name and size etc prints out in terminal, but it still doesn't put it in that directory for some reason.

Comment: Oh, of course, I need to use `fs` to write it. Thanks for all your help!